# How do I join a Windows Active Directory?

Tags: networking, windows, active-directory

We have a "mix-mode" Lab. and we want to migrate to Ubuntu, from Windows.

In this process, how do we add Ubuntu workstations to a Windows Domain / Active Directory ('AD') setup?

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways: using [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) and Winbind or [LikewiseOpen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen).

#### Samba

Samba is more robust and used way more the like wise is. It requires you to edit settings in text files to set up. It may work better for a large lab set up once you have it working. I use this to share files across computers on our windows network at work. There are GUI application [(gadmin)](http://www.gadmintools.org/) that allow you to edit the config but most tutorials give examples on editing the text file.

Using samba here are a number of ways:

- [Samba Active Directory Integration](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-ad-integration.html)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/windows-networking.html
- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html

#### LivewiseOpen

LikewiseOpen is trying to be easy and simple and provides a nice GUI interfaces to change settings. I have not got it to work but I would try Likewise open first. They also have an enterprise option if you would like to pay for support.

Using LikewiseOpen:

- [LikewiseOpen and Ubuntu 10.03](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/likewise-open.html)

Answer (score 4):

**Windows Networking**

Computer networks are often comprised of diverse systems, and while operating a network made up entirely of Ubuntu desktop and server computers would certainly be fun, some network environments must consist of both Ubuntu and Microsoft® Windows® systems working together in harmony. This section of the Ubuntu Server Guide introduces principles and tools used in configuring your Ubuntu Server for sharing network resources with Windows computers.

[Introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/windows-networking-introduction.html)

[Samba File Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html)

[Samba Print Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html)

[Securing a Samba File and Print Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html)

[Samba as a Domain Controller](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-dc.html)

[Samba Active Directory Integration](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html)

SOURCE -> [Windows Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/windows-networking.html)