# How can I join an ubuntu client to a windows domain (server 2008)

Tags: active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I join a Windows Active Directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33592/how-do-i-join-a-windows-active-directory)

I need to add ubuntu 12.10 client to windows server 2008. I tried several commands 
but they did not work. My client could not join. Actually the join starts (in my Server I got the client computer name) but Client ubuntu did not ask for the domain user name, login is only local.  I tried those command for joining:

```
sudo apt-get install likewise-open5
sudo domainjoin-cli join mydomain.com Administrator
```

after this command my system had not joined the domain.

Note : am install DNS server only 
before give this command i need to give static ip address manually??????